# Своеобразная ситуация работы JavaScript.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с некоторой ситуацией. Для меня показалась она очень своеобразной. Взгляните, пожалуйста, на два варианта делания одного и того же. Один из них верен. Другой - нет. Если кто понимает почему, прошу объяснить. Если кто не знает `Ext`, то это не страшно. Его принцип работы тут не при чем.

```
App.data.RegistrationData.submit = function() {

    function getParams() {
        var res = {};
        var act = "reg";
        var first_name = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-first_name').getValue();
        var second_name = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-second_name').getValue();
        var password = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-password').getValue();
        res = {
            act: act,
            first_name: first_name,
            second_name: second_name,
            password:password
        };
        return res;
    };

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://server/',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        params: getParams(), //Тут параметры для запроса
        success: function(resp) {
           // Суксесс
        },
        failure: function(resp) {
            alert(resp.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

И вот второй вариант

```
App.data.RegistrationData.submit = function() {

    var res = {};
    var act = "reg";
    var first_name = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-first_name').getValue();
    var second_name = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-second_name').getValue();
    var password = Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-password').getValue();
    res = {
        act: act,
        first_name: first_name,
        second_name: second_name,
        password:password
    };

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://server/',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        params: res, //Тут параметры для запроса
        success: function(resp) {
           // Суксесс
        },
        failure: function(resp) {
            alert(resp.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPD1**:
Объясню, как программа работала.
Как и полагается в первой ситуации, во инициализации параметров `Ext.Ajax`-запроса, в качестве параметра `params`, должно ставиться значение, возвращаемого функцией `getParams()`. Но так сделали не все браузеры. На сервер было отправлено пустое значение параметра `params`. Долго не мог понять в чем дело, пока вдруг, не ткнув пальцем в небо и не поменяв на второй вариант, по логике идентичный, дело не имело успеха. Так вот **ПОЧЕМУ** же функция возвращала данные *после* того, как запрос на сервер уже был отправлен?

Comment: не все браузеры, это кто?

Comment: ммммм, что-то мне подсказывает :D IE

Comment: Safari на iPhone. Не поверите!

Comment: Ого! А можно поподробнее про сборщик мусора и про ваш вариант, отправив это в ответ, а не в комментарий. Ваша идея достойна уважения!

Comment: Перенёс в ответ... Ого - это значит заработало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы 1 варианта, по сравнению с 2:

1. Работа с функцией - это создание лишнего момента, как для понимания так и для производительности
2. Делать функцию на 1 раз, это ооочень ответственное решение, в данном случае не оправданное ( но бывает и другая ситуация: много кода находятся на 10м уровне вложенности, и что-бы он не занимал место, и лучше читался, можно сделать функцию, хотя она и будет вызываться 1 раз, но для структурированности это будет большой плюс )

Общая проблема:

Зачем мусорить переменными? Если действительно есть необходимость отдельно ( а не в AJAX запросе ) объявить параметры, то точно:

```
var param = {
  act: 'reg',
  first_name: Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-first_name').getValue(),
  second_name: Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-second_name').getValue(),
  password: Ext.getCmp('reg-inp-password').getValue()
};
```

Ошибка 1 варианта:

Возможно в IPhone::Safari не верно реализован сборщик мусора...

Можно попробовать:

1)

вместо:

```
    return res;
```

использовать:

```
    return {
        act: act,
        first_name: first_name,
        second_name: second_name,
        password:password
    };
```

2)

вместо:

```
function getParams() {
```

попробовать

```
var getParams = function (){
```

3)

вместо :

```
var res = {};
```

попробовать

```
var res;
```

4) Совсем фантастика:

переименуйте функцию ( пусть будет qwerty123 ), м.б. в родительских ns она есть

Comment: Вы хорошую идею подбросили по сокращению кода! Вы молодец!  
А по поводу второго вашего пункта, тоже надо принять, хороший совет!
И по поводу третьего: может еще сверху и утечка памяти будет, я не знаю, но проблема была в неверной работе программы.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать. А я и не задумывался про существование сборщика мусора :-()

Comment: Оказался "фантастический" вариант! Еще раз спасибо за помощь!